# concatenate a column vector to the end of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to add a column vector at the end of a matrix as follows :

```
import numpy as np
datas=[[1,2],[3,4]]
temp=[1,2]
datas=np.array(datas)
temp=np.transpose(np.array(temp))

np.append(datas,temp,axis=1)
```

But I'm getting dimension mismatch error?

How do I do this properly then?

Comment: datas is (2,2), temp (2,).  To concatenate on axis 1 temp needs to be (2,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add one dimension to temp so that both the array have same dimension

```py
import numpy as np
datas=[[1,2],[3,4]]
temp=[1,2]
datas=np.array(datas)
temp=np.array(temp)[:, np.newaxis] ## this adds new dimension 

np.append(datas,temp,axis=1)
```

you can also do it using concatenate function like below. It will perform better if you are concatenating more than two arrays. Here you create python list ls in a loop and then concatenate them

```py
ls = [datas,temp]
np.concatenate(ls, axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you rewrite this without `np.append`?  That's a poorly conceived function.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend you just use np.expand_dims() and then np.hstack()

```
datas=[[1,2],[3,4]]
temp=[1,2]

#Expand the dims of temp
temp = np.expand_dims(temp,1) 

#Stack horizontally
np.hstack((datas, temp))
```

```
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [3, 4, 2]])
```